# High temps on MoBo?

Tags: motherboard, temperature

Just built myself a new PC and checking out my temps with HWMonitor it shows that most things are fine, except for the motherboard... Any suggestions?

It's an ITX unit and I have built it in an [SG13](https://www.silverstonetek.com/en/product/info/computer-chassis/SG13/)

- MoBO: AsRock A520M-ITX
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600 with stock cooler
- GPU: GTX 1060
- I have a 140mm fan mounted in the front.

[image]

It seems odd to me that there are just these 2 temps that are sky high...

Comment: Is there an actual problem? Temperature sensors are often inaccurate.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 no problem. I think I was just wanting reassurance :D

Comment: It could be a SMBus device with multiple sensor inputs and two of them are unconnected. What does your BIOS or specific motherboard tool say?

Comment: Good shout, I will check it out